How to send GA4 Client id in shopify with orders
We have shopify website, we are sending transaction id with every purchase in GA4 and as well as in shopify.
now we want client id as well in shopify on every orders.
This is possible? if yes then if anyone has any way or idea. Please help
I want answer of my problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
